# Can we think of a hypothetical experiment to determine the exact position of an object?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Here is an extract from the book "The Elegant Universe"- "When we bounce a wave off of an object, the information we receive is only enough to determine object's position to within a margin of error equal to the wave's wavelength".
I was wondering why this is so? Can we imagine to set up an experiment in the laboratory to determine the **exact** position of an object by sending a beam of light?

Comment: Heisenberg would like a word with you about what you mean by 'determine'...

Comment: So you dont care about the object but about the wave you send? But what is the question?

Comment: Suppose we have a ball placed somewhere on the ground. Now we wish to measure its exact position by sending a beam of light. How can we do this?

Comment: You can't measure it's exact position, because no measurement is perfectly precise. But you can get arbitrarily close by using sufficiently high-energy light. Brian Green says that you can't measure position to within more than a wavelength, so the solution is to get a very small wavelength--also known as a very high energy. People will say this has something to to with Heisenberg uncertainty but it doesn't really; Heisenberg uncertainty gives a relation between measuring position and momentum, and you said you *only* care about position, not momentum. So this will work fine.

Comment: What makes you think your object *has* an "exact position" to measure?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of quantum mechanics. The electron has a wave function which will not be perfectly localized at a position. From the wave function we get a probability distribution of it's position and since the wave function was not perfectly localized the electron will have a non zero probability of being at more than one position at any time.  This is what Brian Greene means when he talks about wavelength. If you try to be precise in determining exact position of electron you begin to "see" its "wave" nature. But its wave nature necessarily entails the fact that the electron is not perfectly localized in position.

Comment: you must reread the first question. For a moment forget about an electron and imagine we have a ball and we wish to locate its position by sending a wave towards it?

Comment: isn't it that one can "perfectly" localise the wave function in position space but then it becomes "perfectly" delocalised in momentum space?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, obviously you can determine the exact position of an electron (disregarding the experimental errors) says the uncertainty principle. But since they (momentum and position) don't commute hence you totally lose the information of momentum about the electron!

Summary: Know the exact position and you lose momentum, know the exact momentum you lose the information about the position!!

Also if the system is in an eigenstate then the uncertainty is lost!